# Play EA Cricket 2007 on M1

Tags: macos, cricket-2007

Other than Windows Emulation, is there any other way to play the **EA Cricket 2007** Game on **Macbook** with M1/M2(Arm) Chip? The Extra files which were for Different Patches like IPL are not so necessary, just the game itself would be amazing for the nostalgia.

Comment: Highly doubt there's way other than using Windows emulation, since the game itself is not for Mac (even for older version). Can I ask you why using emulation can't be your solution?

Comment: There is no specific reason other than just wanted to try out something new, since I had played this game on Windows Natively as well as Windows Emulation on Linux and Mac. So just wanted to try other emulations like maybe PlayStation.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the comment, the game does not support Mac, so there is no way to play it natively.

However, you can still use Windows emulator to play PC version as you stated in the comment, and [PCSX2](https://github.com/TellowKrinkle/pcsx2) to play PS2 version. Since you mentioned it, there's also [AetherSX2](https://www.aethersx2.com/archive/?dir=desktop/mac), that is created primarily focused on to work smoother on Apple Silicon (M1/M2 and its variants).

Disclaimer: I'm not associated with PCSX2 and AetherSX2's developer team. These are what I've chosen to play PS2 games on my Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. Can you also share any links to the PS2 images of of EA Cricket 07, that would be really helpful

Comment: Sorry, this site does not answer to [that kind of question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *site policies prohibit questions of the following types: ... Piracy, and support with pirated games ...*